# Proof that asymptotic approximation on interval plus monotonicity (decreasing) implies uniformity?

Tags: asymptotics, uniform-convergence, perturbation-theory

I am having a difficult time verifying the following theorem, and hope that someone can lend me a hand.

Holmes, in his book *Introduction to Perturbation Methods (Second Edition)* states:

"Theorem 1.4: Assume $f(x,\epsilon)$, $\phi(x,\epsilon)$ and  $\phi_0(\epsilon)$ are continuous for $ a \leq x \leq b$ and $0 < \epsilon < \epsilon_1$.

(a) If $f \sim \phi$ for $a \leq x \leq b$, and if $|\phi(x,\epsilon)|$ is monotonically decreasing in $\epsilon$, then this asymptotic approximation is uniformly valid for $a \leq x \leq b$."

*part (b) is not relevant to this question*

When he writes $f\sim\phi$, he implicitly means as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$. Furthermore this means that (at any fixed $x_0 \in [a,b]$) given a $\delta >0$ one can find an $\epsilon_0 > 0$ (generically dependent on $x_0$) such that

$$ 0 < \epsilon < \epsilon_0 \Rightarrow  \ |f(x_0,\epsilon) - \phi(x_0,\epsilon) | < \delta |\phi(x_0,\epsilon)|$$

Part (a) of the theorem says that if $|\phi(x,\epsilon)|$ is monotonically decreasing with $\epsilon$ (for all $x \in [a,b]$), then one can find an $\epsilon_*$, independent of $x$, such that the above inequality holds whenever $0<\epsilon<\epsilon_*$ (i.e. the asymptotic approximation is uniform on $[a,b]$).

I've tried showing that $Min\{ \epsilon_0 \}_{x_0 \in [a,b]} > 0$ but keep having a difficult time relating what happens at different points $x$ in a useful way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $x_1 , x_2 \in [a,b]$, then given $\delta>0$ you know that there exist $\epsilon_0(x)$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
|f(x_1,\epsilon) - \phi(x_1,\epsilon)| \leq \delta |\phi(x_1,\epsilon)| \quad \text{for} \quad 0 < \epsilon < \epsilon_0(x_1), \\
|f(x_2,\epsilon) - \phi(x_2,\epsilon)| \leq \delta |\phi(x_2,\epsilon)| \quad \text{for} \quad 0 < \epsilon < \epsilon_0(x_2).
\end{eqnarray}
**Edited**: I understand the monotonicity of $\phi$ to be as follows:
\begin{equation}
\phi(x,\epsilon_1) \leq \phi(x,\epsilon_2) \quad\text{if}\quad \epsilon_1 < \epsilon_2,
\end{equation}
so $\phi$ decreases as a function of $\epsilon$ as $\epsilon$ decreases -- which is rather the opposite of what 'monotonically decreasing in $\epsilon$' usually means.

The monotonicity of $\phi$ in $\epsilon$ can now be used in two ways: first, for every $x_i$, you can estimate $|\phi(x_i,\epsilon)|$ by its value at the rightmost point of the $\epsilon$-interval:
\begin{equation}
|\phi(x_i,\epsilon)| \leq |\phi(x_i,\epsilon_0(x_i))|.
\end{equation}
Second, without loss of generality, you can assume that $\epsilon_0(x_2) > \epsilon_0(x_1)$, such that $(0,\epsilon_0(x_1)) \subset (0,\epsilon_0(x_2))$. Since $\phi$ is monotonically decreasing in $\epsilon$, you can therefore estimate
\begin{equation}
|\phi(x_1,\epsilon_0(x_1))| \leq |\phi(x_1,\epsilon_0(x_2))|.
\end{equation}

**Edited**: Therefore, to find a uniform upper bound for the $\epsilon$-interval, you should look at
\begin{equation}
\min_{a\leq x \leq b} \epsilon_0(x).
\end{equation}

Comment: Doesn't monotonically decreasing imply that if $\epsilon < \epsilon_0(x_i)$ then $|\phi(x_i,\epsilon)| \geq |\phi(x_i,\epsilon_0(x_i))|$ instead of what you wrote in your second equation? And similarly for your third equation (given your ordering $\epsilon_0(x_2) > \epsilon_0(x_1)$)?

I am starting to believe that what both you and Holmes mean by $|\phi(x_1,\epsilon)|$ being a monotonically decreasing function of $\epsilon$ is that it decreases as $\epsilon \to 0$. Is that right?

Comment: Ah! I now understand the confusion. Yes, I didn't even think of that, but that's what I understand is going on -- that $\phi$ decreases as $\epsilon \to 0$. Which is rather the opposite of the usual definition of `$f$ is decreasing in $x$', which means that $f$ decreases as $x$ increases. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense, but I still can't get all the way through the proof (btw, thank you for your answer and your patience). So, I agree with your equations two and three given decreasing monotonicity of $|\phi(x,\epsilon)|$ as $\epsilon  \downarrow 0$. Now, say I am not interested in finding the biggest interval in $\epsilon$ for which the approximation is uniform, rather just any such interval. Following the spirit of you answer, I should be able to prove that if $\epsilon_0(x_2) > \epsilon_0(x_1)$ then I could use $\epsilon_0(x_2)$ in place of $\epsilon_0(x_1)$ for the $x_1$ estimate?

Comment: As far as I can see, you can obtain a uniform bound by defining $\epsilon_* = \min_{a\leq x \leq b} \epsilon_0(x)$, which is precisely the opposite of my suggestion in the last part of the answer. I guess I was thrown off by the 'reverted' monotonicity of $\phi$ as well. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: But then we are back to having to show that $min \{\epsilon_0(x)\}_{a \leq x \leq b}$ is not equal to zero.

Comment: That should be no problem, since $0 < \epsilon_0(x_1)$ for every $x_1$ in the closed (in particular, compact) interval $[a,b]$.